# Heroku app crashing while generating wtforms csrf token only when accessed from a custom domain on chrome

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, heroku, flask-wtforms

First time deploying to heroku, but everything went smooth. But after i added a custom domain things started going wrong.

My website has a newsletter form on the landing page and it works well when i access it using the heroku domain: abcdef.herokuapp.com, but if i access it using www.abcdef.com, it returns 500 error and the logs show this:

```
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756194+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-02-27 23:47:39,755] ERROR in app: Exception on /soon [GET]
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756214+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756215+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756216+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756217+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756218+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756219+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756219+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756220+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756221+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756222+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756223+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756223+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756228+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756228+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/application/views.py", line 46, in soon
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756230+00:00 app[web.1]:     form = NewsletterForm()
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756230+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 212, in __call__
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756231+00:00 app[web.1]:     return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756232+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 88, in __init__
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756233+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(FlaskForm, self).__init__(formdata=formdata, **kwargs)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756234+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 278, in __init__
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756234+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.process(formdata, obj, data=data, **kwargs)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756235+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 132, in process
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756236+00:00 app[web.1]:     field.process(formdata)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756237+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/csrf/core.py", line 43, in process
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756237+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.current_token = self.csrf_impl.generate_csrf_token(self)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756238+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 134, in generate_csrf_token
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756239+00:00 app[web.1]:     token_key=self.meta.csrf_field_name
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756240+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 47, in generate_csrf
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756240+00:00 app[web.1]:     setattr(g, field_name, s.dumps(session[field_name]))
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756241+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756242+00:00 app[web.1]:     payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756243+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756243+00:00 app[web.1]:     json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756244+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756245+00:00 app[web.1]:     return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756245+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 51, in dumps
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756246+00:00 app[web.1]:     return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':'))
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756247+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756248+00:00 app[web.1]:     **kw).encode(obj)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756248+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756249+00:00 app[web.1]:     chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756250+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756251+00:00 app[web.1]:     return _iterencode(o, 0)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756251+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756252+00:00 app[web.1]:     o.__class__.__name__)
2017-02-27T23:47:39.756258+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

I'm using python3, but that shouldn't play a part, since this works perfectly when i access it using the heroku url.

I'm using a domain from namecheap and it seems to be well configured, i'm getting the correct redirection, it seems there's an issue with the csrf token generation, but i can't understand what.

EDIT: 
Just realised, it only happens on google chrome. Firefox and safari work as expected.